# Django Test for tutorial not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I am working on going through the tutorial at - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing.I am working on AuthorCreateViewTest to create a test for the AuthorCreate view and I have an issue that I can't figure out. Please see the issue that I facing below. I have attached the code from the project also that I think is relevant to this issue. I am sure that it is simple but I am new at coding with Python and Django. Please help if you can so I can continue my training.

***Issue/Result***

```
C:\Project\django_projects\locallibrary>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...............[(41, 'Set book as returned')]
F[(41, 'Set book as returned')]
.[(41, 'Set book as returned')]
..........
======================================================================
FAIL: test_logged_in_with_permission (catalog.tests.test_views.AuthorCreateViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Project\django_projects\locallibrary\catalog\tests\test_views.py", line 459, in test_logged_in_with_permission
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 403 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 27 tests in 5.632s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

***Views.py***

```
class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    ######################################################
    # You can set the initial values like this
    ######################################################
    initial = {'date_of_death': '05/01/2018'}
    ######################################################
    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
```

***test_views.py***

```
class AuthorCreateViewTest(TestCase):
"""Test case for the AuthorCreate view (Created as Challenge)."""

def setUp(self):
    # Create a user
    test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
    test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')

    test_user1.save()
    test_user2.save()

    permission = Permission.objects.get(name="Set book as returned")
    test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
    test_user2.save()
    # Create a book
    test_author = Author.objects.create(first_name='John', last_name='Smith')

    # Check permissions for test_user2
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=test_user2)
    perm_tuple = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Permission.objects.filter(user=test_user2)]
    print(perm_tuple)

def test_redirect_if_not_logged_in(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('author_create'))
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/catalog/author/create/')

def test_redirect_if_logged_in_but_not_correct_permission(self):
    login = self.client.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
    response = self.client.get(reverse('author_create'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

def test_logged_in_with_permission(self):
    login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
    response = self.client.get(reverse('author_create'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: you are doing a reverse of author_create instead of  renew-book-librarian  ``` # code from docs  
    def test_redirect_if_logged_in_but_not_correct_permission(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('renew-book-librarian', kwargs={'pk': self.test_bookinstance1.pk})) ```
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

Comment: This should be testing the author_create view which only uses the 'catalog.can_mark_return' permission but it seems that I can't set that permission for the user in my test case as follows otherwise I get an error saying that permission doesn't exist in the available user permissions:
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name="catalog,can_mark_returned")
        test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
        test_user2.save()

Comment: Okay I found the solution. Basically I just used the add_author permission and it resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.